# Скриншот объекта

Tags: c#, screenshots

Можно ли сделать скриншот объекта. Например на форме есть панель, на панели другие кнопки или рисунки, можно ли как нибудь сфотографировать эту панель?

Comment: Наверное вы об [этом][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881317/c-sharp-windows-form-control-to-image

Comment: Да об этом спасибо